# Can VS2010 Workflow Designer auto arrange layout?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

In VS2010 WF4 workflow designer is there any way to get it to auto arrange the layout?  I want to add a new step near the top of a workflow and I can't see any way to easily make room for the new item.   The process flow underneath where I want to add the new step is a switch statement with several branches; it doesn't even seem to be possible to multi-select items and move them all down to make room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way, other than adding what you want to add and then deleting the .layout file, forcing it to generate a new layout. Make sure you back up the file in case the new arrangement is worse than the old.

Comment: OK thanks, I wonder if that's a gap in the market for a Visual Studio extension; if you could get hold of enough information to do it

Comment: This certainly would be a useful one!

Comment: The .layout file is only there in WF3, in WF4 the layout is embedded in the XAML file. But other than that the answer is correct and you can't. And to make things worse you can't even group select a number of activities to drag a group around at the moment. The group select is coming in .NET 4.5 though,

Answer (score 2):

Expand your DataSet.xsd tree and delete XSS File...

```
DataSet.xsd
--DataSet.cs
--DataSet.xsc
--DataSet.xss <-- Delete this one...
--DataSet.cs
--DataSet.Designer.cs
```

Comment: WF doesn't use .xss files. DataSets do, but the question isn't about those.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adventurous, you can run code such as this (back up your XSS file first, this code will overwrite it!).  The code will auto-arrange the shapes in the designer neatly.  You can tweak the constants for best effect.  Their meanings should be obvious.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AutoArrangeXss
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutoArrange(yourXssFilePath);
        }

    static void AutoArrange(string xssFile)
    {
        const int xPad = 80;
        const int yPad = 20;
        const int maxY = 1500;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xssFile);
        var ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;

        var shapes = doc.Descendants(ns + "Shape").ToList();

        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        int columnW = 0;
        foreach (XElement shape in shapes)
        {
            int Height = int.Parse(shape.Attribute("Height").Value);
            int Width = int.Parse(shape.Attribute("Width").Value);
            if (Width > columnW) columnW = Width;

            shape.Attribute("X").Value = X.ToString();
            shape.Attribute("Y").Value = Y.ToString();

            Y += Height + yPad;

            if (Y > maxY)
            {
                X += columnW  + xPad;
                Y = 0;
                columnW = 0;
            }

        }

        doc.Save(xssFile);

    }
```

Comment: WF doesn't use .xss files. DataSets do, but the question isn't about those.

Comment: While this does not answer the posted question, this does help me, so thank you.