# Workflow 4.5 designer and rearranging layout

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4

I'm in Vs 2012 and I've started a v4.5 Workflow FlowChart type in the designer.

I built a several steps saved, brought it back up the next day, added some more in between and saved. Came in next day and now it's getting tight.  The flowchart arrows are hard to see.

Is there anyway to let the designer rearrange the layout to be more optimal?  Allow me to add some more and it be easier to follow afterward?

Comment: Have a look at the following answer:

[Auto arrange the layout][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129522/can-vs2010-workflow-designer-auto-arrange-layout

Comment: yeah nice thought.  No .layout file since I'm using VS 2012 / 2013.  But thanks.